# How far should circuit be from solenoid

Tags: solenoid

I am creating a circuit which is controlling a solenoid valve and I was wondering what is a safe distance to keep this circuit from the solenoid valve. Circuit includes an ESP module and some other deep components like resistor capacitor and some TIP122 transistor.

I am planning to keep the solenoid valve within 5 millimetres of the circuitry and the solenoid valve takes around half an ampere current and is controlled by a 12 volt DC.

Would the electromagnetic radiation from the solenoid cause any harm to any of the components or ESP microcontroller?

Comment: if you do a proper design 0mm. it depends on your circuit and how you drive the coil.... Best is a current controlling PWM signal slight above human ear frequency... 16-20kHz. Nothing a normal µC should bother.

Comment: *Would the electromagnetic radiation from the solenoid cause any harm to any of the components or ESP microcontroller?* A solenoid is ususally operated with a **DC voltage** and that means that the circuit will only emit some EM waves when you activate or deactivate the solenoid. When there's a DC voltage across the solenoid it has a **static magnetic field** around it. EM waves are **varying** (over time) magnetic (and electric) fields. Just make sure you have a **flyback diode** in parallel with the solenoid, without it the transistor will be damaged when the solenoid is switched off.